# Acer 7551g-6477 ATI 5650, drivers not responding, cannot complete system assessment

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card

i just bought an Acer Aspire 7551G with the radeon 5650, running windows 7 64. i've tried both the drivers available from acer, and the drivers available from amd, and with both, i cannot complete the windows system assessment to enable aero.

i've tried installing windows 7 32, and that was able to complete the assessment properly, but the system became unstable and would freeze randomly.

Has anyone encountered this and know what the problem is and how i can resolve it? i am very upset that this new laptop has this kind of problem.

i even tried the registry hack to enable aero manually, but when i try to switch to that in the personalize screen, the system freezes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contact the retailer. Random freezes during quite normal operation: could very well be a hardware problem, and then one can try as much user magic there is without solving the problem.

Maybe it is a known problem at the retailer, and then you can quickly get specific help.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the only solution I've gotten so far was from the manufacturer to restore to system default( factory ) settings & drivers. Any drivers I've tried have always been unstable, even the ones from the official Acer website.